# H2O MOJO Runtime: Cannot find MOJO implementation backend

Tags: java, aws-lambda, h2o, automl

I'm trying to run a function on AWS Lambda that loads my H2O MOJO model from S3 and makes a prediction based on function input. My plan is to make a prediction endpoint using API Gateway.

However when I call `ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.MojoPipeline.loadFrom(...)` I am met with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find MOJO implementation backend!
at ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.MojoPipelineFactoryService.getMojoPipelineFactory(MojoPipelineFactoryService.java:46)
at ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.MojoPipeline.loadFrom(MojoPipeline.java:58)
...
```

Below is my method throwing the exception:

```java
  private static MojoPipeline loadMojoPipelineFromS3(LambdaLogger logger)
      throws IOException, LicenseException {
    try (S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(DEPLOYMENT_S3_BUCKET_NAME, MOJO_S3_OBJECT_KEY)) {
        logger.log(
          String.format(
              "Loading Mojo pipeline from S3 object %s/%s",
              DEPLOYMENT_S3_BUCKET_NAME, MOJO_S3_OBJECT_KEY));

        S3ObjectInputStream s3is = s3Object.getObjectContent();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/model"));
        byte[] read_buf = new byte[1024];
        int read_len = 0;

        while ((read_len = s3is.read(read_buf)) > 0) {
            fos.write(read_buf, 0, read_len);
        }

        s3is.close();
        fos.close();

      MojoReaderBackend mojoReaderBackend =
          MojoPipelineReaderBackendFactory.createReaderBackend("/tmp/model");
      MojoPipeline mojoPipeline = MojoPipeline.loadFrom(mojoReaderBackend);

      logger.log(String.format("Mojo pipeline successfully loaded (%s).", mojoPipeline.getUuid()));

      return mojoPipeline;
    }
  }
```

Can anyone help me debug this error? I haven't been able to find anything online.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on the mojo runtime library that you used. Use the one that you get when you download your MOJO pipeline from H2O DAI. `mojo2-runtime-api` also offers the same methods to load the MOJO pipeline (`MojoPipeline.loadFrom()`). E.g. If it's a maven project and if you used the mojo runtime api as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
    <artifactId>mojo2-runtime-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Use the below instead:

First install the dependency to your local file repo using the below command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<<folder where the mojo runtime jar is stored>>/mojo2-runtime.jar -DgroupId=ai.h2o -DartifactId=mojo2-runtime -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then add the below block in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
    <artifactId>mojo2-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <!-- NOT RECOMMENDED THE SYSTEM SCOPE WAY. INSTEAD, INSTALL IT IN YOUR LOCAL REPO
         USING THE COMMANDS GIVEN ABOVE
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/<<h2o>>/mojo2-runtime.jar</systemPath>
        OR
        <url>file://${basedir}/my-repo</url>
    -->
</dependency>
```

Hopefully the above should work! Make sure the path of `pipeline.mojo` is correct .